Gravitational field in the equatorial plane of a thick hollow hemisphere
I have a homogeneous thick hollow hemisphere with inner and outer radii $r_1, r_2$ respectively and density $ρ$. I need to find the direction of the gravitational field in every point at the equatorial plane (which is a circle of radius $r_1$). My first approach was to draw the vectors but it seems to easy, so i decided to calculate it by the following way:
$$\vec g=-G\int_{r_1}^{r_2}{dM\over r^2}\hat r$$
where
$$dM=ρdV=ρr^2drsinθdθdφ$$
and inserting this in the integral i get
$$\vec g=-Gρ\hat r\int_{r_1}^{r_2}dr\int_{0}^{π}sinθdθ\int_{0}^{π}dφ$$
which gives $$\vec g=-2πGρ(r_2-r_1)\hat r$$ But i am not sure if that is correct. What are your opinions?

Check-my-work questions are off-topic on this site, so your question is likely to get closed.

You seem to be treating $\hat r$ as a constant and taking it out of the integral.

Your notation is confusing you: the $r^2$ in the denominator isn’t the same thing as the $r^2$ in the volume element. They’re only the same when you calculate the field at the center.
